# Remote form stopped working after update to Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-2

I've recently updated one Rails 2.x applications to Rails 3 (3.0.20 at the moment, but the ultimate goal is 3.2.x). I noticed that one remote form stopped working properly. It sends requests and new records are created, but to tell that a full page reload is required.

There is absolutely nothing special in its definition:

```
form_for(@comment, :remote => true, :html => html_options) do |f|
   <%= f.label :username, 'Name/nickname' %>
   <div class="text">
     <%= f.text_field :username, :maxlength => '60' %>
   </div>

   <%= f.label :email, 'E-mail' %>
   <div class="text">
     <%= f.text_field :email, :maxlength => '120' %>
   </div>

   <%= f.label :content, 'Content' %>
   <div class="textinput-longer">
     <%= f.text_area :content %>
   </div>

   <%= f.submit 'Add Comment', :value => 'Add comment' %>
<% end %>
```

There is also an event bound to the form

```
    $('form#comment').bind({
      submit: function() {
        // disable inputs and change CSS
      },
      ajaxComplete: function(event, response, request) {
        // insert comment
        new Comment(response, this);
      }
    });
```

I suppose that some script specific for Rails 2.x might be missing?

Comment: before your form tag something is missing?

Comment: did you include `jquery_ujs` in your javascript asset

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
remote_form_for(@comment, :html => html_options) do |f|
```

or

```
form_for(@comment,{ :remote => true, :html => html_options}) do |f|
```